# Unable to veto a stage-specific @Specializes class in Websphere 8.0

Tags: websphere, cdi

In my first foray into the world of JSF and CDI, I've been trying to use the @Specializes annotation to override behaviour in a managed bean in unit tests only. We have the MyFaces CODI jars in the WEB-INF/lib, and the unit test aspect works just fine, i.e. my Mock specialization is picked up and used:

```
@ProjectStageActivated(ProjectStage.UnitTest.class)
@Specializes
class MockCustomerSearchScreenBean extends CustomerSearchScreenBean {
...
```

That works fine when the project stage really *is* unittest, but when it's anything else, the WAR startup fails with

```
org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: org.apache.webbeans.exception.inject.InconsistentSpecializationException: Specialized bean for class : class bla.bla.MockCustomerSearchScreenBean is not enabled in the deployment.
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.checkSpecializations(BeansDeployer.java:653)
```

I know the @Observes ProcessAnnotatedType is firing during bean discovery because I can see the veto flag has been set on the ProcessAnnotatedType by the CODI ActivationExtension, and I also wrote my own extension which explicitly vetos the Mock version, but the container is still determined to try and use the specialized version and not the 'normal' one. I also tried wrapped the AnnotatedType to not advertise the @Specialization annotation.

There's no simple way for me to not deploy the mock subclass to my desktop server either.

Is there any way to persuade WebSphere's version of open web beans to ignore the Specialization based on project stage (or some other factor I can control)?

Answer (score 0):

WAS 8.0 uses a quite old version of OpenWebBeans. This issue was fixed long ago in OpenWebBeans. I would move to 8.5+. And/or try the same with @Alternative (but with BDA switched off).